# Why jQuery children selector is targeting the parent?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm working on a navigation bar that displays a dropdown menu on click. 
The script simply toggles the class to display it.

```
$(".dropdown-btn").click(function() {
  $(this).children(".dropdown").toggleClass("expanded");
});
```

Adding the styles, it works.

```
.dropdown {
    display: none;
}

.dropdown.expanded {
    display: block;
}
```

The problem comes when I add a nested dropdown menu. When I click on the nested ".dropdown-btn", the script toggles the class of the child dropdown (as it's supposed to) **but** it also toggles the class of the parent! To better explain what I mean, inspect the fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/3rm3ny1j/

I have two questions. What is the reason of this behavior? What is the best solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because a click event will bubble up the DOM and trigger the click event on its ancestors.

Add `.stopPropagation()` and you can prevent that:

```
$(".dropdown-btn").click(function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    $(this).children(".dropdown").toggleClass("expanded");
});
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/sgtngqh1/)**

Answer (score 2):

Your `.dropdown` is nested inside a `.dropdown-btn` causing any further clicks to trigger the parent event.

By separating the trigger and the dropdown you can stop them triggering upwards.

See this updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3rm3ny1j/2/

Answer (score 1):

You have *nested* `.dropdown-btn` elements, and you don't [`stopPropagation`](http://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/), so clicking on one also clicks on all its ancestors.

NB: In order to answer this I had to follow a link to an external site so I could see all of your problem. Stackoverflow questions should stand on their own merits. SO even has snipit functionality now which does the same job as JSFiddle but locally.

Comment: I will investigate how that snipit functionality works here. So far I've seen most people explaining multiple code issues with JSFiddle.

Comment: JSFiddle has been around for longer than snipits and was, historically, the good way to show live demos, but its never been considered acceptable to make the question depend on the JSFiddle to be able to understand it.